# Can anyone explain exhaustMap in rxjs in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, rxjs

```
import {
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpParams,
  HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { exhaustMap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return this.authService.emitUser.pipe(
      take(1),
      exhaustMap((user) => {
        if (!user) {
          return next.handle(req);
        }
        const modifiedReq = req.clone({
          params: new HttpParams().set('auth', user!.token!),
        });

        return next.handle(modifiedReq);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

This is an interceptor file which modifies the request url by adding 'auth' query params and a value as a token that we get from the user object here. But I cannot understand what is happending inside the exhaustMap.

Comment: exhaustMap is a higher order operator, just like switchMap or concatMap. They all behave differently when another emittion arrives while the inner request is still pending. However, you call a take(1) ahead, so it really doesn't matter which higher operator you choose. You could switch to switchMap if that makes you more comfortable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exhaustMap` is a higher order pipe operator, which subscribes to the piped observable and for (nearly) each emitted value, returns a new observable, coming from the function you passed to it.

But what should happen if the returned observable has not completed yet, but the source observable emits a new value. That's where `exhaustMap`, `switchMap`, `concatMap` and `mergeMap` differ.

In your case `exhaustMap` is used, which means if a new value is coming from the source observable, but the previously mapped observable is not yet completed, the new value coming from the source observable will be ignored.

It will be ignored until the previously returned observable has completed. After that new values from the source observable will be mapped to the inner observable again.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this code `this.authService.emitUser` which is called a `source observable` emits a user let's say **Theri** and that is being processed in the `exhuastMap` while processing if the `source observable` emits another user **Muthu** the `exhaustMap` still tends to process the user **Theri** until it is completed. Once it is processed the user **Theri** then only starts processing the user **Muthu**.